# How to automatically center the alignment of all output cells?

Tags: output-formatting

How can one change the default output alignment from left to center?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`$PrePrint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PrePrint.html) to add the option `TextAlignment -> Center` to all output cells in the current session:

```
$PrePrint = Style[#, "Output", TextAlignment -> Center] &;
```

[image]

To restore `$PrePrint` to the default value use

```
$PrePrint =.
```

If the notebook contains output cells created before `$PrePrint` is invoked, you can use

```
Scan[SetOptions[#, TextAlignment -> Center] &, Cells[CellStyle -> "Output"]]
```

to change their alignment.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the stylesheet of the notebook to style all output cells accordingly:

[image]

You can find several questions on how to permanently install such stylesheets or how to programmatically change it in the official documentation and on this site, for example [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStylesheets.html) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197655/how-do-i-add-a-style-programmatically-without-specifying-the-stylesheet).